# how to get sheet name in excel 2010 without Cell function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am looking for a way to obtain an excel sheet name using excel formulas (without VBA) in Excel 2010 and without using CELL function, which contains language pack specific argument.
Can you help?

Comment: You could try [this](https://www.howtoexcel.org/how-to-generate-a-list-of-sheet-names-from-a-workbook-without-vba/)

Comment: What is the "language pack specific argument" that you're referring to, and why is it an issue?

Comment: @ashleedawg There is a comment in the help for CELL about this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60173&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: The first argument of the CELL function is language-specific text, which is different in each language pack. In result, the CELL function will return error if calculated using a different language version of Excel. For example, if you create a formula containing CELL while using the Czech version of Excel, that formula will return an error if the workbook is opened using the French version.

Comment: @JvdV: Thank you for suggestion, but it does not work any longer as the GET functions are not available in currect Excel versions.

Comment: @Maciej I think I am on the current Excel channel, and the example in the link works for me. NB. GET is not a spreadsheet function, it is an Excel4 macro command.

Comment: @JvdV That is a great link: I never knew about this feature ... and now we have gone full circle and have LAMBDAs using the Name Manager! In terms of the OP's question, I think this 'RefersTo' will get the worksheet name of the calling cell: `=REPLACE(GET.CELL(32),1,FIND("]",GET.CELL(32)),"")`

Comment: @JvdV: Yes, you can list the names of worksheets, but the sequence changes, when you move sheets. Try to move a sheet first then add a new sheet and a new position to be displayed in the the following row.

Comment: @JvdV: You are right! The formula =REPLACE(GET.CELL(32),1,FIND("]",GET.CELL(32)),"") returns a list of just one element, which is the name of the sheet the cell is located in. BIG thank you!

Comment: @JvdV: This is not an issue. The key is that it works with any language pack and on Excel from 2010 up.

Comment: @JvdV: this doesn't work well: try to change a sheet name - it is not reflected in the cell automatically. You need to recalculate it manually.

Answer (score 0):

**♦REVISED - WORKAROUND FOR EXCEL 2010♦**

*--Caveat: not the most 'elegant' soln but does the job for Excel 2010--*

---

**Step 1**

Open workbook, enable track changes with following options(♣):

[image: Track changes]

[image: Options]

♣ *Legacy option for 365 variant - std. feature in Execl 2010*

---

**Step 2**

Select all sheets (Ctrl + Shift + PageDown from left most tab).  All sheets now highlighted - select common free cell (here, conveniently A1).  Modify. Save workbook.

[image: Modifying common cell across all sheets]

---

**Step 3**

Review changes | List on separate sheet:

[image: List changes on separate sheet]

[image: History Tab ~ Protected (!) ~]

---

**Step 4**

Your question specified requirement for function to extract sheet names - conveniently, this is a requirement given the history sheet is protected and cannot be manipulated directly (would love to know how to unprotect - but that is another topic/forum).  For now, it suffices to say the function desired is a simple direct reference into the desired tab:

```
=History!F2
```

[image: Function to extract sheet name]

---

**PREVIOUS SOLN (OFFICE 365 COMPATIBLE VERSION EXCEL)**

Use Formulatext

*(caveat: assuming you have Office 365 compatible version of Excel)*

---

Function/approach to return the name "Sheet1" using functions / no VB:

1] Reference any cell in Sheet1 - you can do this from anywhere feasible within the same workbook -

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

[image: Function in formula bar contains text of interest]

*FUN FACT: Sheet name for active tab will reflect (and continue to reflect until return carriage) if any other tab is activated during the compilation of a formula in the function bar / main ribbon (or directly within excel cell for that matter)*

---

2] Use `Formulatext()` to retrieve the sheet name as a function with a cell reference:

[image: FormulaText]

---

3] Tidy up by discarding text at/after ! and = sign (assuming Office 365 compatible version Excel, I've incorproated let to condense the function/ etc.

```
=LET(sh_,FORMULATEXT(A1),MID(sh_,2,LEN(sh_)-4))
```

[image: Text functions to tidy up/extract sheet name]

Caveat: exclaimation marks present within sheet names will require different functions as req. in step 3 (minor stage).

---

Comment: This is nice solution for modern Excel, but I need solution for Excel 2010 (please read the original question above), which doesn't have LET or FORMULATEXT.

Comment: Ahh in the header of the Q - darn gosh fair point.  Ta for the compliment though :)

Comment: @Maciej - tbh I am unaware of how to do this with the restrictions you've put in place (no 'cell' function and no VB) - is there a use case for this 'challenge' or is it purely for awareness/note?

Comment: I need to prepare and provide a spreadsheet to persons with Excel 2010. It just would be really convenient to me to be able to use worksheet names in formulas. The formulas would work even after changing a worksheet name.
BTW, the CELL formula is very inconvenient, because it's first parameter depends on the user language pack.

Comment: Not sure about this 'user language pack' @Maciej but that may be irrelevant for our purpose - thanks for context all the same -- have provided a workaround - as I say, far from elegant - requires a bit of prep, but far more effective than manually typing out all sheet names I'd say (assuming more than, say, 5-10 sheets concerned).  Up/down vote as you deem fit for the sake of future users.  Ta

Comment: Ahh - and, well, far from 'dynamic' - you may be better off with one of the other solns' proposed in comment block - ps- if calc is on automatic then surely no manula calc required?  My soln is more of a 'one-off' as its a bit cumbersome to udpate - yikes - you have some language pack idiosyncrocy with frequently changing tab names in an Excel 2010 environment - sounds like a highly specific/bespoke problem.  Best of luck mate

Comment: It seems there is no solution to my problem. Anyway, thank you for a good try.

Comment: Disagree - tongue in cheek might be to upgarde to 365? Seriously though perhaps look into Inside Office (File, Account -) registering a/c free of charge and can permit access to 365 functionality (even if using 2010) - I did this way back before 365 launched. No - I don't work there/have shared/friends family working there - just mentioning plausible workaround.  sorry couldn't be of more assistance !!